# Is the Version Information for ODBC #define "ODBCVER" Standard?

Tags: c, odbc, unixodbc

In trying to write generic code for compiling against multiple versions of ODBC headers, I was curious if [`SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT_STREAM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/retrieving-output-parameters-using-sqlgetdata?view=sql-server-ver15) would be available.  e.g. one could write:

```
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

#if ODBCVER >= 0x380  // e.g. ODBC version >= 3.80 (*not* 3.08)
    // SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT_STREAM is available
    ...
#endif
```

Looking at the [unixodbc sql.h](https://github.com/lurcher/unixODBC/blob/09fdd8cfa7765665339f6ea10b9cbdc1433d8cf8/include/sql.h#L11), I saw that it said:

```
 /****************************
 * default to 3.51 declare something else before here and you get a whole new ball of wax
 ***************************/
 #ifndef ODBCVER
     #define ODBCVER 0x0380
 #endif
```

*(I take it the comment is out of date (?) as it seems 0x0380 means 3.80.  @TallTed notes that this is distinct from 3.08, which one might think "3.8" meant in conventional [semver-speak](https://semver.org/).)*

So this form of definition lets you do your own `#define` of `ODBCVER` before the inclusion of `<sql.h>` and possibly "downgrade" it to compile to only support older standards.  If you fail to do so, then it will be the highest version the header can support.

...but I can't find anything about `ODBCVER` in the Microsoft docs.  Is there actually no standard way to sense what definitions are in the header file you are compiling against?  Would something like `#ifdef SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT_STREAM` be better as a form of "feature-detection" on `sql.h`?

Comment: `#if ODBCVER >= 0x380  // e.g. ODBC version is > 3.8` is erroneous. `0x0380` means `03.80` (three-dot-eighty) not `3.8` (three-dot-eight)

Comment: (Microsoft, which maintains the ODBC specification, fosters this error, as they regularly reference ODBC `3.8`, but as this is a *later* version of ODBC than `3.50`, `3.51`, and `3.52`, it *must* be `3.80`.)

Comment: @TallTed Thanks for the note, incorporated into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`ODBCVER` might not appear in the documentation but it is definitely supported. It appears all through the ODBC headers that are part of the Windows SDK.

For example, the latest SDK on my current system at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\sql.h` along with 7 other files in the same directory reference `ODBCVER`.

Comment: Good to know.  [It's in iODBC's sql.h also](https://github.com/openlink/iODBC/blob/d9293505804e775488582321420e427464e6c3ce/include/sql.h#L82)--which also has the "test if it's defined before overwriting it with a default" pattern, and downgrades the API.  One can probably take for granted that it is defined after you have included sql.h...and if not, it's the problem of the person with the weird build environment who is building your code to sort out otherwise by defining it with `-DODBCVER=0x...`.